# IE9 and Z-index: element disappearing behind parent on hover

Tags: internet-explorer, hover, internet-explorer-9, z-index

I've got a weird bug that's only occuring in IE9. Not in IE8 or IE10, nor any other browser.

Basically, I've got a whole bunch of 'divs' set out as tiles, ala Pinterest. I have CSS set to

```
tile:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

so that any overflowing elements like box-shadows, etc. will appear over non-hovered tiles when I hover.

HOWEVER,

On IE9, elements inside that tile are disappearing behind the background on hover. Basically the z-index of the tile is moving the background of the tile above some (not all) of it's containing elements. It doesn't happen if I do this

```
tile {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I could probably work around this by giving every element inside a position: relative and z-index: 1, but that's not a good solution. Why is this happening?

Comment: In internet explorer you need to set the z-index for the parent and children.  Have you tried setting a z-index of the parent to 0 or something.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out just after posting. The tile doesn't have a z-index when not hovered. So it'd be fine on load, fine on hover, and then disappear on un-hover. Solution is to give

```
tile {
  z-index: 0;
}
.tile:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
```